# using fgets for substring search

Tags: c

This code returns sub string position, but I'm concerned about `gets` being deprecated, and that I should use `fgets` but I don't really understand how to use it with the pointer, cause I've tried using the `fgets` format for both `gets` and I get compiler warnings.

This one is functional:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    char str2[100];
    char *pch;

    gets(str);
    gets(str2);

    pch = strstr(str, str2);

    if (pch != NULL)
        printf ("%d\n", pch - str);

    return 0;
}
```

This is how I used `fgets`:

```
fgets(str, 100, pch);
fgets(str2, 100, pch);
```

Comment: [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) requires an opened, readable `FILE*` (thus the `f`) . I cannot fathom how the posted code doesn't puke warnings, if not outright errors, when substituting those `fgets` calls.

Comment: @WhozCraig actually `fgets(str2,100,pch);` only emits only a warning, even if it's actually an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gets()` has been deprecated because it does not take a size argument to specify the maximum number of bytes to read from the `stdin` stream. A sufficiently long input line will cause undefined behavior because `gets()` will write beyond the end of the destination array: this is considered a major security flaw so this function has finally been removed from the recent versions of the C Standard (from C11). Do not use this function.

`fgets()` should be used as a replacement: your mistake is the third argument is the input stream, `stdin` in your case. The compiler complains that `pch` has the wrong type.

Note that unlike `gets()`, `fgets()` stores the newline at the end of the buffer, size permitting, so you must remove it from the second string before testing if it is present inside the first string.

Also note that `pch - str` has type `ptrdiff_t` which may be different and larger than `int`, you must cast it as `(int)` as the `printf` argument for `%d`, or use `%td` on C99 compliant systems.

Here is a simple way to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    char str2[100];
    char *pch;

    // read 2 strings from stdin:
    // fgets takes an array, its size and a stream as arguments
    // it returns a pointer to the destination array if successful
    // it returns NULL at end of file or upon a read error.
    if (!fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin))
        return 1;

    if (!fgets(str2, sizeof str2, stdin))
        return 1;

    str2[strcspn(str2, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the trailing newline if any

    pch = strstr(str, str2);

    if (pch != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", (int)(pch - str));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `gets` is not deprecated any longer, because it was completely removed from the C standard since C11 (formally,  ISO/IEC 9899:2011).

Comment: @M.NejatAydin: good point. Answer amended. Most compilers just complain about deprecation because they support older versions of the standard by default.